# how to capture wireless data frame using scapy in python

Tags: python, wireless, tcp, scapy, packet-sniffers

I am using the following code to capture only data packets from a wireless network but following code is not working for the data packets it worked only for management frame. So what changes should be made to capture the data frames?

```
def PacketHandler(pkt) :                                          
   if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) :                      
           if pkt.type == 2 and pkt.subtype == 0 :                
                TCP IP data



sniff(iface="mon0", prn = PacketHandler)
```

code taken from:  http://hackoftheday.securitytube.net/2013/03/wi-fi-sniffer-in-10-lines-of-python.html

Comment: Please format your code properly. Did you make some research about what the differences are between "management" and "data" frames?

Comment: Yes sir .... what i understood is that data packets came in 802.11 frame encapsulation, managment and control frame do not carry data like IP and Port ( as only for managment and control ). I mistakenly write type==0 and subtype==8, but actually i have used type ==2 and subtype == 0 .... aafter that i am not getting how to get IP address and port number ,flag information protocol used....

Comment: New Code That i tried also fail--->                                                                       from scapy.all import *.......... def PacketHandler(pkt):........                                                                    if IP in pkt :..............ip_src=pkt.src ...................                                                             print " IP is " + str(ip_src)..........  sniff(iface="mon0", prn=PacketHandler)

Comment: You need to increase your effort for asking here. Properly format your code, explain in simple terms what you have tried and where the problem exactly is. Otherwise no one will answer.  http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Extremely sorry Jan-Philip Gehrcke    but is there anyway to get ip address and port number out of wireless packet using scapy